# Error when creating EntityManager in JPA2

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I'm trying to create a simple JPA2 app that persists something to a database using the OpenJPA implementation. I'm running Derby and using the default Embedded JDBC Driver. I've been scratching my head over this trying to figure out what's missing. I'm sure it's something trivial, but if someone could look this over and point me in the right direction, I'd be really greatful. Thanks.

Here's my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HelloWorld">
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/StuffDerby</jta-data-source>
        <class>helloworld.entities.Employee</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and when I run this code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorld");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

It fails when calling the createEntityManager() method.

```
406  HelloWorld  INFO   [WebContainer : 0] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.0.0
[1/11/11 12:46:21:377 PST] 0000002f servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet HelloServlet in application HelloWorld. Exception created : <openjpa-2.0.0-r422266:935683 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.String incompatible with javax.sql.DataSource
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:208)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at helloworld.entities.controller.EmployeeManager.getEntityManager(EmployeeManager.java:37)
    at helloworld.entities.controller.EmployeeManager.getEmployee(EmployeeManager.java:188)
    at helloworld.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.osgi.web.extender.OsgiDirectoryProtectionFilter.doFilter(OsgiDirectoryProtectionFilter.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with javax.sql.DataSource
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:834)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:594)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1489)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:507)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:432)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:104)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:939)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:930)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:626)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:193)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: looks to me like the thing at the jndi reference is a string, not a datasource. are you sure that in the jndi population bit that you are not putting a string with the jndi reference of the datasource, rather than the result of the lookup of that name (you don't post it so i can't see). There should be some j2ee mumbo jumbo about resource ref or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: 
>     java.lang.String incompatible with javax.sql.DataSource
> ```

In other words, `java:comp/env/StuffDerby` points to a `java.lang.String` instead of `java.sql.DataSource`. Fix it accordingly in the server config.

Comment: isn't the datasource defined in some xml file, and the AS have to instantiate it?

Comment: Indeed, it's usually definied as JNDI resource where you can specify the FQN as resource type. Can be done by either a XML file in webapp or a webbased admin. Likely the FQN was `java.lang.String` instead of `java.sql.DataSource`. If not, then it's probably a bug in AS.

Comment: yup.. I've grown the habit of immediately assuming a bug in the AS. And I haven't used any AS in a production project..

Comment: found this in my webapp.xml <env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>StuffDerby</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value> ... </env-entry-value>
 </env-entry>. Although it doesn't let you change it to a DataSource type.

Comment: See, there's the culprit. Fix/alter "it" so that it lets you change it. It's only hard to give detailed assistance on this since it's unclear what exactly "it" is. Is it the One? Is it the mate of Pennywise? You might consider asking a new question if you really can't figure "it".

Comment: Sorry, "it" being the xslschema for web.xml (not webapp.xml). The <env-entry-type> can't be a java.sql.DataSource.

Comment: What is the `<env-entry-value>`? The datasource? On a second thought, although I don't do Websphere (anymore), but I would expect it to be `<res-type>` or something like that where you need to specify `java.sql.DataSoruce`.

Comment: Well, i ended up deleting that from the web.xml. It got put there by IBM RAD when I added a JPA facet to the project. Ended up just using JNDI to get the datasource. It now works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.